# Watir script occasionally returning Net::ReadTimeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have a Watir script, that occasionally and unpredictably returns this error:

```
Net::ReadTimeout
```

I searched this error and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452276/watir-get-sometimes-a-netreadtimeout-error-by-launching-chrome-browser) already asked. I followed the top answer, and implemented this:

```
attempts = 0
url = "https:/www.google.com/"
begin
doc = Watir::Browser.start url
rescue Net::ReadTimeout
  retry
end
```

but I'm still getting the same timeout error.

I've never had any connection issues with my network. I get the error on both an Ubuntu and a Windows 10 machine. My code goes through an average of around 30 iterations before this error manifests itself. I'm using Chrome.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a syntax error. Add a line with `begin` above the `doc=`

Comment: Oh weird, that appears to work. What does begin do?

Comment: Typically you would put only the line(s) of code that could cause an exception after the &#39;begin&#39;. You catch the exception with `rescue` and end the block with `end`. This allows you to gracefully handle errors you are aware of and still raise errors that are not expected

Comment: Is your page loads takes more than 60 seconds?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Generally it's much less, but yes it does when this error manifests.

Comment: Did you read my answer in the question you have for reference ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Your answer states that it's a Selenium bug and that there's no way to increase the load time, right? I was hoping somebody has found a workaround since then.

Comment: No, I said it's the problem when you click a button navigate to the next page not for `goto`, Can you read my answer once again? page_load works perfectly for `goto`

Comment: @Rajagopalan Sorry, english isn't my first language. Are you saying that if I use `go_to` instead of `start` and then set the timer with `page_load`, it should work?

Comment: Okay, give me some time, I will as an answer.

Comment: Can you check my answer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above error was thrown when the page load time exceeds for 60 seconds so write the following code for page load

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox,http_client: client
b=Watir::Browser.new driver
b.goto "www.google.com"
```

Now your code would wait for 120 seconds for any page load which has been caused by `#click` and also wait to load the `url` by `goto` method.

Comment: I actually got a timeout even with this, so I'm using 99999 seconds.