# Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout using selenium-webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, jasmine

I use selenium-webdriver gem, Ruby 2.4.4, Rails 4.2 to run Jasmine tests using Firefox.
But unfortunately in most cases I have this error **: Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout**.

Logs from Selenium show me that test run, but then there is a huge delay after running tests before closing browser.
Could you please advise how to fix that? Or maybe someone had the same issue?
Maybe I can add some code fix this in jasmine_helper.rb ?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The above error was thrown when the page load time exceeds 60 seconds so write the following code for page load

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox,http_client: client
```

Now your code would wait for 120 seconds for any page load which has been caused by `#click` and also wait to load the url by `goto` method.

Comment: You are using Ruby Selenium Binding, yes?

Comment: I'm using selenium-webdriver gem v3.8.0

Comment: The above stated error is coming from Selenium, If page loads exceeds 60 seconds, this error would be thrown, If you include the above code in your program, this will be resolved.  Here is the same another question where I have answered the same, You may read that question and then see my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431267/watir-script-occasionally-returning-netreadtimeout-error/50432231#50432231