# Watir Raising Error, "Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>" When Attempting To Create New Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I am working on a rails application that pulls data from a REST endpoint and then scrapes a production website that consumes said endpoint to ensure the contents is present and displaying correctly. I have had pretty good luck with Nokogiri. However, we have a few react pages that load dynamically. Nokogiri cannot handle the dynamic content.

I am attempting to use the gem Watir. It appears to be exactly what I need. However, every time I attempt to  run `Watir::Browser.new` the following exception is thrown:

```
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
from /home/thomas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.7/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:217:in `rbuf_fill'
```

All pages I have attempted to hit do load in a timely manor in the regular chrome browser. I have checked firewall setting and disabled my company's VPN. Still no luck.

I just recently setup the watir gem and installed the chromium driver by running, `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`.

Would anyone know why Watir would fail in this way?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04 with WSL
- Ruby 2.6.7
- Rails 6.1.4
- Watir 6.19.1

Comment: I had this issue on one project. It only happened at startup. Catching the exception and then retrying a couple of times solved it. Not a great solution, but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @JustinKo. I did try something similar suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452276/watir-get-sometimes-a-netreadtimeout-error-by-launching-chrome-browser

However, that did not seem to work. It would also be infeasable for me to setup such a system. This application will be scraping hundreds of pages at a time. I would not be able to allow it to delay for a minute or more on each item.